# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' -object has no attribute for my .csv file

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe

I am writing a code which reads the data from .csv file and prints plot from the data from the columns. I have been trying to  fix this error, checked previous posts. (changed advanced options -> use system operators; do not seem to work.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVUgF.jpg)

```
#Reading Airfoil data from file
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
dataset = data
data['L/D ratio'] = data['C(Lift)']/data['C(Drag)']
data
 
x = data.AoA
y = data.C(Lift)
z = data.C(Drag)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(x, z)
plt.title("Angle of attack (X) Drag and Lift coeficcient relation")
plt.xlabel('Angle of attack')
plt.legend(["C(lift)", "C(drag)", "AoA"])
plt.ylabel('C(lift) and C(drag)')
```

Comment: The DataFrame doesn't have a column named "C". Why aren't you accessing the columns the way you do in the `L/D ratio` calculation?

Comment: @mechanical_meat changed it, and worked, thanks! however, I saw on the tutorial videos the script similar to this one, that is why I used this one.

Comment: It's probably best to just avoid using so-called "dot" notation for accessing columns. The name of the column can clash with a method and might produce an unexpected error. I'm kinda surprised a tutorial would recommend that, and maybe another tutorial would be better.

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).